# Angular Parent-Child Controllers with "Controller As" Syntax

Tags: angularjs

Is it acceptable or "proper" to *pull* ojects from a one controller while binding the `ng-model` to *a different* controller (for example, when using `<select>` and `ng-options`)?  Is there a clean / simple / elegant way of implementing dependent forms and or parent-child controllers in Angular?

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="CountriesCtrl as countries">
      <select ng-if="countries.mode === countries.modes.select"
                   ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries.items track by country.id" 
                   ng-model="countries.selected"></select>
       /* snip */
  </div>

 <div class="row" ng-controller="StateCtrl as states">
      <select ng-if="states.mode === states.modes.select"
                   ng-options="state as state.name for state in countries.selected.states track by state.id" 
                   ng-model="states.selected"></select>
       /* snip */
  </div>
```

[image: Parent-Child Example with Controller As Syntax]

Comment: I think the "more proper" way would be to have the Dropdown add/edit/delete component be a directive that takes the countries.selected.states through an attribute

Comment: `CountriesCtrl` isn't the parent controller here, `LocalesCtrl` is.  each of the others are siblings.  This doesn't even look like it should work, as written.  Can you post a better [mcve] of this (not screenshots)?